# asp.net webforms login with custom database

Tags: asp.net, authentication, webforms

and thanks in advance for anyhelp you can provide.
My problem is i have this schema for example
table users: id, name, password, category_id | table category: id, name (with client and admin values for example (and dont want to change this schema).
I would like to know what needs to be donne in order to make a login with the default functionalities like the role authorization system of the .net framework.
I have already looked in customMembership and custom roleProvider Implementation, but i get stuck right in the login which uses neither of these two classes.

```
         protected void LogIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    if (IsValid)
                    {
                        // Validate the user password
                        var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>(); 
                        var signinManager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationSignInManager>();

                        // This doen't count login failures towards account lockout
                        // To enable password failures to trigger lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
    //fails here
                        var result = signinManager.PasswordSignIn(Email.Text, Password.Text, RememberMe.Checked, shouldLockout: false); 

                        switch (result)
                        {
                            case SignInStatus.Success:


IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"], Response);
                            break;
    ...
```

Do i need to implement an usermanagerProvider?